# Heroku rails console output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm running a large update on my models (generating a random public_id) and it's taking forever on heroku.

Running the command:

```
Episode.where(public_id: nil).find_each do |e|
  e.set_public_id
  e.save
end
```

Is taking forever and it's a black box.  Running it locally I could see the progress through database commits.

Is there a way to see what's going on?  Is there a different way I should be running this command?

Comment: How many episodes with public_id nil do you have? Why don't you use `e.save!` instead?

Comment: You could add a `p` command inside the method to print some sort of progress to see it in the console.

Comment: Or start second console instance and check how many records have public_id ;)

Comment: I have 2.3 million records, took a couple hours locally.  Episode.where(public_id: nil).count on heroku didn't return fast enough so I canceled the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a rake task & use [the logger](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#the-logger) to inform whats happening

```
#lib/tasks/episode.rake
require 'rake'

namespace :episode do
  desc "your description"
  task :update => :environment do
    Episode.where(public_id: nil).find_each do |e|
      Rails.logger.info "updating #{e} ..."          
      e.set_public_id
      e.save
    end
  end
end
```

Then run it

```
heroku run rake episode:update
```

and you can tail the logs in another terminal window with

```
heroku logs -t
```

Comment: You should also be able to use a `puts` instead of `Rails.logger` and it should just print the contents right to the console you have open. You would be able to avoid the `heroku logs -t` command this way.

Comment: Is there any reason this should take longer on heroku?  I saw one update so far, looked like one batch worth (which took ~30m to even start).  Locally it took a couple hours.  This is 2.3 million records.